# What is the warp modifier for?

Tags: modifiers, objects

What is the [warp modifier](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/warp.html#warp-modifier) for, and how is it used?
Even when I fill in the *From* and *To* fields, so that the modifier is not red, I still can not figure out what it is so post to do.

[image: Warp modifier]

---

When I set up the modifier just like is shown in the manual, it does nothing.
[image: animated gif]

Answer (score 7):

The warp modifier can also be used to **wrap** an object: the ***to*** object  controlles the direction to where the ***from*** object is wrapping the object (holding the modifier).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

The warp modifier produces results similar to user gestures of

**proportional editing**.

The blue cube has a high vertex density.  The from and to are animated in rotation.

[image]

Comment: You can also think of this as the tuggy modifier because it tugs, but in a totally nice way.

Comment: That darkblue text on darkgrey background is very difficult to read.

Comment: You can also think of this as the wapr (pronounced whopper) ... modifier.  Whopper results.

Answer (score 2):

The warp modifier deforms a mesh as if some force acted on it. The force starts at the "start" object and ends in the "to" object. The "start" object center and the radius determine which vertices are affected. The texture option has an effect similar to the texture of the displace modifier.

You need to increase the radius in order to see something, because there is no effect if the radius is smaller than the distance from the source. The scale and rotation of all three involved objects does matter (even if the "from" and "to" objects are empties), so it is best to apply the scale and rotation before playing.

Also note that the manual uses a grid, not a plane without subdivisions.

I found this tutorial useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzMVZa5OVBY