# Soccer goal net movement

Tags: animation

I am creating a soccer animated series.

Picture a soccer goal, how do i make the net move smoothly once the ball makes contact with it?

Thanks

Comment: Try to use a hook modifier on a subdivided plane. Additionally the mesh effect can be obtained using the wireframe modifier. A (more accurate) alternative is to use Animation Node as you can do nearly what you want (ball proximity and influence on the net).

Comment: thanks, will try

Comment: Check this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98910/how-to-create-and-design-hoops-net-and-attach-ot-to-a-hoop/99074#99074

Comment: @Cgslav, I came to the exact same solution  ;)

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61540/dynamic-proportional-edit-connected-to-an-object/61542#61542

Answer (score 2):

You have several solutions. The more realistic one would be to use a cloth simulation then use it as a *Mesh Deform* to deform your net. You have 2 much more simpler solutions, with *Lattice* and, more flexible, *Warp* modifiers:

**Cloth:** It's the most realistic solution.

- Create a plane about as large as your net. Give it a *Physics* > *Cloth* simulation, enable its *Cloth Collision* option. Pin it on its border.
- Create a ball, give it a *Physics* > *Collision* simulation.
- Animate the ball and simulate the movement of it hurting the net and falling on the ground. The net should deform accordingly.
- In the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Display*, change the display of the plane, choose *Wire*.
- Bring your net object, give it a *Surface Deform* modifier, put it above the other modifiers. Choose the plane as *Object*. Click on the *Bind* button. Now the plane should deform the net.

[image]

**Lattice:**

- Create a lattice and in *Object* mode, scale it so that it encompass your net object. Subdivide it a bit.
- Give your net object a *Lattice* modifier. Choose the lattice as *Object*.
- Assign a vertex group to the whole net vertices except the borders that are supposed to be pinned, choose this group in the *Lattice* modifier.
- Put the necessary modifiers below the *Lattice* one.
- Select your lattice, in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Shape Keys*, create a basis shape key and add another one, keep this second one selected.
- In *Edit* mode, deform the lattice so that it deform the net the way you want.
- Back in *Object* mode, play with the value under the shape keys list. You'll be able to create keyframes to animate.

[image]

**Warp:**: This method is more flexible as it allows you to animate more easily.

- Create 2 empties, in front and behind your net.
- Give your net object a *Warp* modifier. Choose the 2 empties as objects *From* and *To*.
- If a part of the net is supposed to be pinned, select the vertex group in the modifier.
- In *Falloff Type*, choose the kind of deformation you want, you might prefer *Curve* to create your own one.
- You can move the empties, therefore animate the movement of the bump.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so in terms of animating this, id need to increase the range per frame?

Comment: could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: well say the ball hits the top of the net and then rolls down. i guess I would need a couple shape keys to show the net movement as the ball hits and rolls down

Comment: oh ok yes that's the limit of this method, I'll explain Warp modifier which is more flexible, and I'm trying with cloth but i need to fix some issues with this method

Comment: well thats the effect im trying to get with jerseys. Like can the warp modifier move a jersey as the player is running? If so I assume it would need cloth modifier also? if you get what im trying to say

Comment: it really depends on the degree of realism you're looking for, if you want a tissue-like simulation, nothing better than Physic > Cloth, but it's not a domain I'm familiar with, I'm digging though

Comment: Thanks sir. Somewhat realistic, dosnt have to be anything EA Sports like. also, if u can answer plz, wud u know how to add text to the soccer jersey? like a flat text? even though the jersey isnt completely flat, how do i lay it on the jersey?

Comment: you need to use Image Texture node, it's the kind of question that has already been answered, if you don't find the answer, post a new question, because it's completely different from the current topic  ;)  I'm trying to find a solution with Cloth, not easy to get the ball repelled by a surface...

Comment: yeha i ask many questions in this forum, not all get answered, so i guess whilst i have a pro im gonna ask lol my bad

Comment: well I'm not a pro yet  ;)   for the jersey you'ill find an answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Comment: Ok, I've edited with the cloth solution  ;)

Comment: Can you show me what you did so I can see?

Comment: I mean I've edited my answer to add the cloth solution, actually it's the same as the one linked by cgslav above

Comment: also check the link given by Lemon

Comment: hah i didnt even see lemon. Thanks sir. Ive been using blender for 3 months, just when I figure something out Something else goes haywire. BETAproblems.com

Comment: @KamranAli If this answer has helped you, you can 'accept' it. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work