# Shell based deformation in blender

Tags: mesh

Is it possible to do in blender a "shell based deformation"? Basically given a mesh I want to pull few points and distort the whole mesh in a way that curvature due to distortion and pulling is minimized.

So I don't want to get triangles that are stretched too much, and high changes in curvature.

To summarize, I have my triangular mesh with vertices V1,...,Vn, I specify a subset of vertices with their final destination, and at last I modify the whole mesh in a way that distortion is minimized.

The technical term I think is called "thin shell deformation", I can provide you the formula if my description isn't clear.

The following picture might help:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if you are asking for a very precise mathematical requirement or something more casual. Proportional edit does something similar and with weight data via weight painting you can have much control.  Perhaps these have more artistic intentions than mathematical.  There are addons that produce a surface from equations. Warp modifier does something similar with weight painting.  You may see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43501/what-is-the-warp-modifier-for/43502#43502 .... Python programming language is available as well. Lattice modifier.

Comment: Ideally a very precise mathematical requirement, in practice something which is close enough.